# Why do I have to organize a these vector as a 2x4 matrix to extend the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the vectors u =(1,-2,5,-3) and v =(2,3,1,-4). To extend these vectors in to a basis of R4 I first create the 4x2 matrix with u and v, then set it to equal the null space. However, I could tell that this is wrong, though I can't explain why. Then I transposed it to be the 2x4 matrix, solve for the basis of null space and got the answer I wanted.

I recognize that if I solving for the nullspace of the 4x2 matrix would give me a vector in R2, which can't extend the basis, and doing so for the 2x4 would give me vectors in R4 that will extend my basis. But aside from this reason, I can't figure the logic underneath that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its *row* space, so to use this method you must make the given vectors rows of the matrix. If they are the columns of the matrix, then the null space that you compute will be a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply the $2\times 4$ matrix by the vector of unknowns, what you get is a $2$-vector, which components are the dot product of your two given vector by the vector of unknowns. By solving for the unknown you are finding elements of the orthogonal complement of the subspace generated by the two given vectors, where 'orthogonal' is defined by the dot product.